# mysql_insert_id(); returns zero. Auto increment is working fine

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script and when I run it it inserts a string into a field called **patch_name** in a table called **patches**. The table has an auto incrementing ID called **PATCH_ID**

Everything works fine and is inserted.The **PATCH_ID** increments as expected.

However **mysql_insert_id()** echos out **0**

**Code**

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO patches (patch_name)
VALUES ('hi')");


$insertID = mysql_insert_id();


echo $insertID;
```

Comment: Take a look at your functions.  Don't mix up APIs.  `mysql_()` functions are different from `mysqli_()` functions.

Comment: First like you use `mysqli_*` and the second line `mysql_*`. Look at the difference. `-i`

Comment: is that PATCH_ID a primary key? also better use mysqli_insert_id() as you are already using mysqli_* functions..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using mysqli_* so better use

```
mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

Hope it helps.

Please have a look at [mysqli_insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

Comment: I tired this at first but didn't realize I needed to add the $con ( connection argument)  hence why I tried the other method: mysql_insert_id();

Comment: We are always learning by doing, so please read the documentation and examples carefully and things will be in your favor.

Answer (score 2):

That's easy: Do use the functions of one extension only, do not mix them.

You use MYSQLI for your query, and MYSQL for the inserted id - this will never work.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I thought they were interchangeable and thought nothing of it.

Comment: @William MySQL (ext/mysql) is the old deprecated extension which will be removed in near future. MySQLi is the improved version.

Comment: The last inserted id is bound to the connection being used. And the connection is bound to the matching mysql extension.